# Spring controller not created as singleton

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring controller that I think is getting instantiated more than once based on the object ids I see when I debug through the code.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services/user")
public class UserController{

private UserService userService;

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

public UserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createUser")
public @ResponseBody String createUser(@RequestBody User user) throws UserNotCreatedException {

    try {
        userService.createUser(user);
        return user.getEmail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UserNotCreatedException("User not created");

    }
}
```

Spring configuration file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as 
    beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.controller" />

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="userController" class="com.xyz.UserController">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.xyz.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDaoMysql" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDaoMysql" class="com.xyz.UserDaoImpl" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="template" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
   </beans>
```

I noticed the problem when I realized that userService is null when I make a request that goes through UserController. However; when I put break points, I see that userService does get set in another instance of UserController.

Comment: You have both an autowired instance and a manual configuration for the controller!

Comment: @adarshr Where's the autowired instance? I don't see `@Autowired`...I just see a property. Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other comments in this thread did not take into account the package of the `UserController` class. The supplied Spring config initializes component-scanning on `com.xyz.controller` as the base package. The `UserController` class looks like it is outside of this in `com.xyz` and thus would not be picked up by component-scanning (unless that is a typo @user269091 - which could be your problem!).

I should note that I don't understand why your controller would not be in your `controller` package. It would be cleanest to move the controller there, add `@Autowired` above the line `private UserService userService;` and remove the manual `UserController` definition in the Spring config, so that the component-scanning just picks up your bean automatically and wires up the `UserService`.

With that being said, I really don't see why there would be a problem with what you have shown. Do you have `new UserController()` anywhere in your code? Is there any other Spring configuration?

Answer (score 1):

To build on @adashr's answer

If you remove the manual configuration, then you're now initializing things based on annotations.  The @Controller annotation will correctly create the Controller, but nothing wires in the UserService now

You need a @Autowired for the UserService to instantiate it since your spring config is now annotation driven

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing annotations and bean xml configuration.
If you are using @Controller annotaion, you do not need to define the controller bean in XML.

The instruction

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.controller" />
```

takes care of registering the controller bean for you (your controller bean is inside that package).

I suggest you to use mvc namespace while configuring Spring MVC to keep configuration minimal and more readable.